# what is the use of "@" symbol in the view file while property binding?

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-list-basic',
  template: `
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [@heroState]="hero.state"
      (click)="hero.toggleState()">
    {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>`,
```

I tried angular animations and it works fine, I don't understand this template part, why are they using @-symbol infront of the trigger in the view.

Docs: [here](https://angular.io/guide/animations#states-and-transitions)

Answer (score 6):

Without the "@" you would be binding values to the component.

With the "@" you indicate that the variable (in this example heroState) is an animaton-state and not a value-bind, it will trigger animations you declare.

Comment: Does this @ denotes the element as a host-listener or any other kind of decorator or does it belong to any other category. I am asking this because I never see the use of @ symbol in the view file in angular in any other place.

Answer (score 5):

That is used for triggering **`animations`**, which would load the **`specific styles`** from the styling file when you need it,

In the above when the variable **`heroState`** is **`inactive`** it will load the particular style with the animation

```
animations: [
  trigger('heroState', [
    state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

Comment: I understand your point, But what I am asking is, is this a HostListener or kind of decorator or does it belongs to any other pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the @ is some kind of escape character in angular in html templates. Here it indicates that it is not a bounded value but rather an animation state.

Comment: May be yes, But what is the kind? and do we have any example other than this animation part